# CT or Hall sensor to measure small current?

Tags: sensor, arduino-uno

My project is an energy monitor(my grid is 127V/60Hz), based in Emon lib + Arduino UNO.
I want to measure currents from 50mA - 25A due my range of different loads, I have a CT 30A(SCT013) working fine only with currents > 1A.
I have more two options to try the reading that low currents, would be a CT 5A(200 ohms burden resistor) and a board with ACS712 5A(probably bad choice due mV/A rate).
My idea is "split" 25A in 5 cables or tracks on the board and install the CT 5A on one of these cables/tracks and use an opamp like the picture below:

[image]

Someone can help me please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: There are many possibilities for where the noise is coming from, so post a schematic of the best thing you've tried so far. Note the Uno has an awful ADC, not only high noise and poor resolution, but also does not read well close to the rails. Are you digitisng AC, or using a precision rectifier to get to DC, and if the latter, are you using a low pass filter? Are you scaling for 100mA or 5A full scale with a pre-amp?

Comment: _"I need to measure low AC currents(my grid is 127V/60Hz) like 10-100mA"_ - for what purpose?

Comment: Link to datasheet, please (in the question, not in the comments). How many primary turns did you use?

Comment: Hello friends, thanks for your answers and sorry for my poor data info. I just edited my post and hope to sent correct info.